# How to decompose abstract system design with TDD?

Tags: architecture, tdd

I am reading «Extreme Programming. Test-Driven development." by Kent Beck and came into a a struggle of understanding one idea, possibly simple idea...

For example I would like to create a program that makes currency conversion.
In my head it sounds like: go write a test for a function that takes three arguments:

```
currency_convert(
    from_currency: str, 
    to_currency: str, 
    amount: Union[float, int]
) -> Union[float, int]
```

But I understand that it would be much much better to make data classes which store some things inherited from some abstract class. For example `class Dollar(Currency)`

And here comes a struggle...
How to write in TDD with this amount of enclosures?

This is just the beginning, what about abstract factories, or basically factories. When in plain programming I sit and think which abstracts to bring into an application and so write them, in TDD I do not understand how to create a good design of an architecture.
Should I decompose architecture very well so that tests that I write should be testing abstract layers?
Or should I stick to an iterative programming to the point I refactor code into some classes/abstract classes?

Comment: *"I am reading «Extreme Programming. Test-Driven development." by Kent Beck"* What is that? A book? Kent Beck has written a number of books, among them *Extreme Programming Explained* and *Test Driven Development: By Example*. If you're reading the latter, it literally shows how to use TDD to develop a multi-currency portfolio management system, which includes conversion. Is that not the book you're reading?

Answer (score 1):

> should I stick to an iterative programming to the point I refactor code into some classes/abstract classes?

Usually this one.  "Removing duplication" and "Expressing Intent" are activities that normally take place as part of the "Refactor" task.

It will *sometimes* happen that you discover you are trying to test complex logic in your abstract class, and that using derived classes as the test subjects introduces excessive noise in the test.  One possible solution is to create a test for the base class itself, or for an "empty" class derived from the base class.

(It's a lot more common to solve these difficulties with composition - extracting from your existing code a smaller thing that is easier to test.)